# Overload CPU in Cpanel-WHM

Tags: mysql, sql, cpanel, whm, exim

I noticed my website is suddenly very slow for the past two days, when I check the process Manager I see 270% of CPU is used by the following Command:

/usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/mails.xxx.com.err --open-files-limit=65535 --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/mails.xxx.com.pid

I restarted all services including sql, and exim but it did not help, I killed te process but it comes right back.

Any help will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try to monitor your mysql process with " mysqladmin proc " command, You can find out which user is using high server resources on your server.

Also try to optimize your MySQL with mysqltuner scripts.

http://mysqltuner.com/